# UiNavigation controller in appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I want my navigation controller to be available in my whole application. Is it possible to create a UI navigation controller object in my app delegate and make it available in the whole application? Can I use the navigation throughout the application using this object?

I created an object in app-delegate in Swift. but it doesn't work as expected. In the iPhone-simulator only the navigation bar is displayed and I can't do anything except look at the bar. The background is completely blackened out.

Comment: Where is the code that you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the other answers are adequate so I'll throw in my 2 cents:

in your AppDelegate file you can create a reference to your UINavigationController as suggested

```
    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate {
         var window: UIWindow?
         var firstViewController: FirstViewController?
         var baseNavController: UINavigationController?
         ...
         func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
              firstViewController = FirstViewController(nibName: "FirstViewController", bundle: nil)
              guard let first = firstViewController else { return //you gotta handle this somehow }
              baseNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: first)
              window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
              window?.rootViewController = baseNavController
              window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
         }
    }
```

At this point, you can access your baseNavController anywhere in your project like so

```
if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    print(delegate.baseNavController)
}
```

Comment: i dint understand  the guard statement here . showing error as well .                   
  Variable declared in 'guard' condition is not usable in its body

Comment: remove the guard statement directly assign firstviewcontrolller as rootviewcontroller

showing error
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:

Comment: Are you using Nibs or Storyboards?

Comment: i used storyboard. i got issue resolved thanks for help.there is another issue i want to slide out my side menu over navigation bar currently it slides below it

Comment: let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
unable to access navigationitem i.e. title and leftbuttonitem using above command

Comment: @YashChoukse Have you tried accessing the rootViewController property of the baseNavController?

Answer (score 0):

A `NavigationViewController` needs a `rootViewController`, I guess that you're setting up your code in `AppDelegate` like show:

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())
```

To solve the problem, the `rootViewController` should be a specific `ViewController` not a dummy `ViewController`. 
You should create a `ViewController` like `FirstViewController` and inside `AppDelegate`:

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstViewController())
```

Comment: i have created uiviewcontroller in storyboard all i want navigation controller and bar to be global so i can use it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

In your **AppDelegate** in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function you can add these line of code

```
     let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let firstViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController")
     let navController = UINavigationController()
     navController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
     window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
     window?.rootViewController = navController(rootViewController: firstViewController)                             
     window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: this . FirstViewController() can i use from storyboard ?